# Get Hours and Minutes (HH:MM) from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get only `hh:mm` from date.

How I can get this?

I have tried this :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 108)
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just use the first 5 characters...?

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108)
```

Comment: Should replace 108 by 113 for 24h format

Answer (score 45):

You can easily use Format() function instead of all the casting for sql 2012 and above only

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hh:mm')
```

This is by far the best way to do the required conversion.

Comment: Starting with SQL 2012.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

Comment: I found an interesting article on the performance of FORMAT(), which concludes that it "is expensive", but that it "provide more flexibility and give more intuitive methods". 

It's an interesting and thoughtful article: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: This doesn't take into account the 24hour format, the format command may return `hh:mm` as am/pm.

Comment: @antogerva pass tt to get am pm 

format(Getdate(), 'hh:mm tt')

Answer (score 14):

Another method using `DATEPART` built-in function:

```
SELECT cast(DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) as varchar) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) as varchar)
```

Comment: When I use this, I get, for example, 11:2 instead of 11:02. Is there a way of forcing the minutes to be :mm?

Comment: @MarceloSilva Try my answer

Comment: @MarcelloSilva use the right function: `SELECT cast(DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) as varchar) + ':' + right('00' + cast(DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) as varchar), 2)`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to display 24 hours format use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH:mm')
```

and to display 12 hours format use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hh:mm')
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code shows current hour and minutes in 'Hour:Minutes' column for us.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108) + 
(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) > 12 THEN ' PM'
    ELSE ' AM'
END) 'Hour:Minutes'
```

or

```
SELECT  Format(GETDATE(), 'hh:mm') + 
(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) > 12 THEN ' PM'
    ELSE ' AM'
END) 'Hour:Minutes'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works on 2008R2+ to produce 'HH:MM':

```
select
case
when len(replace(replace(replace(right(cast(getdate() as varchar),7),'AM',''),'PM',''),' ','')) = 4
then '0'+ replace(replace(replace(right(cast(getdate() as varchar),7),'AM',''),'PM',''),' ','')
else replace(replace(replace(right(cast(getdate() as varchar),7),'AM',''),'PM',''),' ','') end as [Time]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast datetime to time

```
select CAST(GETDATE() as time)
```

If you want a hh:mm format

```
select cast(CAST(GETDATE() as time) as varchar(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is syntax for showing hours and minutes for a field coming out of a SELECT statement.  In this example, the SQL field is named "UpdatedOnAt" and is a DateTime.  Tested with MS SQL 2014.

```
SELECT Format(UpdatedOnAt ,'hh:mm') as UpdatedOnAt from MyTable
```

I like the format that shows the day of the week as a 3-letter abbreviation, and includes the seconds:

```
SELECT Format(UpdatedOnAt ,'ddd hh:mm:ss') as UpdatedOnAt from MyTable
```

The "as UpdatedOnAt" suffix is optional.  It gives you a column heading equal tot he field you were selecting to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH')
I used this to get the current hour in apex PL/SQL